# Access fonts in public folder of rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, sass

I want to generate an absolute path to the url to fonts which are stored under a directory named public/fonts in a rails application.

I have an file called fonts.scss.erb - and I've got code that looks like this:

```
src: url('#{root_url}/fonts/my-silly-font.eot');
```

this results in a css file which looks like this:

```
 src: url("root_url/fonts/my-silly-font.eot");
```

I would like the css to output to something like this:

```
 src: url("https://localhost:3000/fonts/my-silly-font.eot");
```

basically the root_url should be replaced from the root_url from the current environment.

Is this possible?

As an aside, the reason for this is that we are having issues with font's which are served up from cloudfront-- we can't seem to get the CORS headers correct.

Comment: Just to clarify - is there any reason apart from them being on CloudFront as to why you're not putting the fonts in the asset pipeline?

Comment: no that's about it-- in the end I ended up putting the @font-face directive directly on the layout page, where I had access to the root_path variable.